# Adapting quickselect for smallest k elements in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, language-agnostic

I know that I can get the Kth order statistic (i.e. the *kth smallest number* in an array) by using [quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) in almost linear time, but what if I needed the *k smallest elements* of an array?

The wikipedia link has a pseudocode for the single-element lookup, but not for the k smallest element**s** lookup.

How should quickselect be modified to attain it in linear time (if possible) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually modifying quickselect is not needed.  If I had an array (called arrayToSearch in this example) and I wanted the k smallest items I'd do this:

```
int i;
int k = 10;  // if you wanted the 10 smallest elements 
int smallestItems = new Array(k);
for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    smallestItems[i] = quickselect(i, arrayToSearch);
}
```

Edit: I was under the assumption that k would be a relatively small number which would make the effective Big-O O(n).  If not assuming k is small this would have a speed of O(k*n), not linear time.  My answer is easier to comprehend, and applicable for most practical purposes.  recursion.ninja's answer may be more technically correct, and therefore better for academic purposes.

Comment: The runtime here is O(nk) in general, where k is the number of elements you want, which is not nearly as good as what Petr is proposing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the other solution is about 10x faster than yours regardless of the big-O notation because it avoids making unnecessary calls. You can check this out pretty easily by coding both up.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that after you use quickselest to find the `k`-th statictic, you will automatically find that the first `k` elements of the resulting array are the `k` smallest elements, only probably not sorted.

Moreover, quickselect actually does *partitioning* with respect to the `k`-th statistics: all the elements before `k`-th statistic is smaller (or equal) to it, and all the elements after are bigger or equal. This is easy to prove.

Note, for example that for C++ [`nth_element`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/nth_element/)

> The other elements are left without any specific order, **except that
>   none of the elements preceding nth are greater than it, and none of
>   the elements following it are less.**

If you need not just `k` smallest elements, but *sorted* `k` smallest elements, you can of course sort them after quickselect.